# Exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Getting Error Message for Exception System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied while accessing  sub site. Able to access root site.

Answer (score 0):

You can troubleshoot your issue as following:

1. Go to subsite Site Settings->site permissions->Check permissions, check if the current user has permission to access this subsite.
2. What’s the browser you used to access the site? Try to use other browser and check if the issue exists.
3. If you encounter this issue in IE, go to Tools->Internet options->Security tab->Custom level->scroll down to User Authentication section, select “Automatic logon with current user name and password” or “Automatic logon only in Intranet zone” and check again.
4. If the issue still exists, you can check the ULS log to get more error message about your issue.

Comment: thanks a lot, the issue was related to SQL sever being configured to listen at port 14333, when actly we had created SPN using 1433 port.So even when I was using system account to access a subsite , it was giving me error.Not really very sure why I was able to access Root site collection though